# Populate recyclerview and select the first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which is populated with a list obtained by API. How can I make the first item from the list to be default selected without clicking on it? I also need the selected item as object in my fragment where I use the `RecyclerView`. Here's my `RecyclerView`:

```
    public class PaymentMethodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PaymentMethodAdapter.PaymentTermsViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    List<PaymentInfo> mPaymentInfoList;
    OnItemInteractionListener mListener;
    PreferenceAdapter mPreferenceAdapter;
    int selectedPosition = -1;

    public interface OnItemInteractionListener {
        void onClick(PaymentInfo paymentInfo);
    }

    public PaymentMethodAdapter(Context context, List<PaymentInfo> paymentInfoList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mPaymentInfoList = paymentInfoList;
        this.mPreferenceAdapter = new PreferenceAdapter(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public PaymentTermsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ItemPaymentInfoBinding mBinder = ItemPaymentInfoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
        return new PaymentTermsViewHolder(mBinder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PaymentTermsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PaymentInfo paymentInfo = mPaymentInfoList.get(position);
        holder.bind(paymentInfo);
        if (selectedPosition == position) {
            holder.mBinder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok_48);
            mListener.onClick(paymentInfo);
        } else {
            holder.mBinder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok_50);
        }

        holder.mBinder.rlPaymentHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                selectedPosition = holder.getLayoutPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPaymentInfoList.size();
    }

    public static class PaymentTermsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemPaymentInfoBinding mBinder;

        public PaymentTermsViewHolder(ItemPaymentInfoBinding binder) {
            super(binder.getRoot());
            this.mBinder = binder;
        }

        public void bind(PaymentInfo paymentInfo) {
            mBinder.setPaymentInfo(paymentInfo);
            mBinder.executePendingBindings();
        }
    }

    public void addOnItemInteractionListener(OnItemInteractionListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public void removeInteractionListener() {
        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify this "default selected"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570788/select-items-in-recyclerview

Comment: Change `int selectedPosition = -1;` to `int selectedPosition = 0;` to select first item

Comment: Well, the first time the list is loaded I want the first item to be already selected and I want that object in my fragment. After that, the user can select any item he/she desires and that object is passed onto my fragment through the listener interface.

Comment: Exactly what @howdoidothis said

Comment: At the current state of your question, "I want that object in my fragment" means nothing to us

Comment: I'm sorry if I was a little bit unclear, but switching the `selectedPosition = 0` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use performClick() function this function  used for item or button to click itself when condition become true. 
ex:

```
    if(positon == 0)
    holder.itemView.performClick();
```